# How to access current security context within a driver in cube.js

Tags: node.js, cube.js

I'm working on a custom [`cube.js`](https://cube.dev) database driver that uses a private http service which accepts arbitrary, raw sql and returns the result as json.

The http service uses `Authorization` header to identify the user (so that it can enforce appropriate access controls).

I was looking for ways in which I can pass [`cube.js` security context](https://cube.dev/docs/security/context) to the driver.

---

I tried steps mentioned in their [multi-tenancy](https://cube.dev/docs/multitenancy-setup) document, specifically the [*Multiple Schema and Drivers*](https://cube.dev/docs/multitenancy-setup#multiple-schema-and-drivers) one.

It only works the first time where I'm able to access the security context in the `driverFactory()` callback. There I initialise the new driver instance with the user's token in `securityContext`.

For subsequent calls though (event with different user!), `cube.js` reuses the same instance. And this is the cause of the problem. I cannot reuse driver between different *application* users.

Is there a way to solve this? Or am I not implementing multi-tenancy correctly here?

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`contextToOrchestratorId`](https://cube.dev/docs/config#options-reference-context-to-orchestrator-id) function (introduced in `v0.29`), in conjunction with [`contextToAppId`](https://cube.dev/docs/config#options-reference-context-to-app-id), to achieve this.

According to the documentation,

> `contextToOrchestratorId` is a function used to determine a caching key for the Query Orchestrator instance. The Query Orchestrator holds database connections, execution queues, pre-aggregation table caches. By default, the same instance is used for all tenants; override this property in situations where each tenant requires their own Query Orchestrator.

---

Thanks to Ivan Vdovin on [Cube.js' community slack](https://slack.cube.dev/) for providing directions +1